# Pink or Bright Pink?

Tags: colour, quality

Sorry for the slightly blurry photo, but what would you say this is?
These two pinks are a little different, very slightly.
Is the above one old pink and the bottom one bright pink?
Or are they both bright pink?

Can anyone send a comparison pic of pink and bright pink?

[image]

Comment: I stood up to take a photo, but then realized I myself can not reliably tell my Pink from my Bright Pink from my Salmon. And even if I could, and even if it was always consistent from the factory over the decades (where coloring methods have changed), sun damage changes the color more than these two show.

Comment: If anyone does take a photo, please use sunlight, and  include a White, and a LtBley for reference in the photo. And a Salmon if you've got it.

Comment: New sets could also have same color deviation. Due to manufacturing process even LEGO could not produce same color consistently across multiple parts for a single set.

Answer (score 4):

[image: dark pink, bright pink, pink]

Top is Dark Pink

Middle is Bright Pink

Bottom looks like Salmon to me, but based on [the old jumper plate](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3794a&colorID=23&in=A) it has to be Pink.

Underneath are Light Bluish Grey and White. Photo taken in sunlight.

Comment: I do not distinguish LEGO pink/purple colors well, but looking at the various pictures Salmon has more Orange in it than any of pictured elements here.